# Multi touch trackpad gestures for Windows (7)

Tags: windows-7, macbook, touchpad, gestures

I have Windows 7 running on my Macbook and I am wondering if it is possible to take advantage of the multi touch trackpad and have (more) gestures, more than the default boot camp drivers give you.

Is there a program out there that allows you to make your own, or even comes with a basic set.

Comment: here at 1 year later, still hoping for such thing to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Apple releases a driver specifically for this the answer unfortunately not. The majority of touch features on Windows 7 is aimed at Touch Screen notebooks and tablets, as well as the Touch Panel LCD interfaces.