# More multi touch macbook trackpad gestures for windows 7 bootcamp

Tags: windows-7, macbook, touchpad

[Duplicating another question](https://superuser.com/questions/4209/multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-for-windows-7) that still doesn't have a positive answer...

I have Windows 7 running on my Macbook and I am wondering if it is possible to take advantage of the multi touch trackpad and have (more) **gestures**. More than the default boot camp drivers give you anyway.

Is there a program out there that allows you to make your own, or even comes with a basic set of **multi-touch *gestures***?

I'm hoping mostly for 3 finger back / forward, 4 finger expose and desktop... And a "Better Touch Tool" where you can configure all of those and more! :P

<sub>By the way, a good *hint* for anyone else with this configuration is to remove "Enhance Pointer Precision" from window's "Mouse Properties". That's if you setup "Tap to click".</sub>

Comment: great question, I would love to be able to do the three finger drag while in windows 7

Comment: so eiu165, are you saying Sathya's answer on using Synaptics drivers didn't work for you?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi touch trackpad gestures for Windows (7)](http://superuser.com/questions/4209/multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-for-windows-7)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi yeah, I even said it way back then. This question doesn't have an answer on the "original". Back then we couldn't "put a bounty" on others questions.

Comment: @Cawas I know. All I did was flag it for closing, which *automatically* generated that comment.

Comment: Why bother closing it? What difference does it make? Also, I'm not sure how to ask this here without sounding tendentious, but wouldn't it make more sense to close the oldest unanswered question in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can take a look at [Synaptics drivers](http://www.synaptics.com/support/drivers). These bring multi-touch for my Envy 14.

For my previous Dell Inspiron 1520, I used [these modded drivers](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/31/enable-multi-touch-gesture-finger-scroll-momentum-and-chiralmotion-on-synaptics-touchpad-in-windows-7vistaxpserver/) to achieve the same multi-touch functionality.

Comment: Keyword here is **gesture** rather than multi-touch... Bootcamp drivers already enable multi-touch.

Comment: The suite adds gestures + MT. Momentum, chiral scrolling, multi-finger swipes et al.

Comment: Seems fair and good enough. Will give it a shot next time!

Answer (score 1):

A Chrome extension is out which enable Bootcampers to swipe back/forth with two fingers for pages. You can get it here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgegfjnccpnkdppohmfgnjalkediapkc

Or search for it yourself:
Swipe Gesture

In google addon store.

All credits goes to antimatter15.com for creating this. It's still at an early stage, but very useful indeed. And as seeing that swiping back/forth is one of the most used multi touch features (at least to my experience) this addon is a godsend. Also has no problem with people running virtual machines, as the addon can simply be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Google for Trackpad++. It's not feature complete, but it does have a few of the things you asked for, a basic set of 3 and 4 finger gestures.

Comment: I have tried trackpad++ in the past, and it had nothing. Seems like it now has something indeed. Unfortunately I can't try it anymore... If someone asserts it's good, I'll gladly change accepted answer, as this seems to be simpler. Also, welcome to SU, @Larry. You should probably add a link to http://trackpad.powerplan7.com/ at very least! ;-)

Comment: I used Trackpad++, it has all gestures but, it damages your system.